# How to bring Angular2's NgZone into a class without typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to use NgZone in a small project, but cannot figure out how to bring it in.  The docs at angular.io say they're for javascript, but seem to use typescript.

[Angular2 docs on NgZone](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/NgZone-class.html)

And every example I find seems to go along with the docs, i.e., typescript:

[Plnkr example of NgZone](http://plnkr.co/edit/lY9m8HLy7z06vDoUaSN2?p=preview)

```
export class NgZoneDemo {
  progress: number = 0;
  label: string;

  constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone) {}
```

We're not using typescript, and I cannot figure out how to bring NgZone into my class to save my life.  What would I have to change in the plunkr to make it usable in a project not using typescript?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ng.core.NgZone` object and inject into your components as described below:

```
var Cmp = ng.core.
  Component({
    selector: 'cmp'
  }).
  View({
    template: '<div>Test</div>'
  }).
  Class({
    constructor: [ng.core.NgZone, function(zone) {
      // Use the zone
    }]
  });
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Using `zone.run()` is in the example unnecessary, since it brings the code back to the Angular 2 framework (which it's already at). To show the functionality of `zone.run()` you must first use `zone.runOutsideAngular()` to get outside of the NgZone of Angular, then you can use `zone.run()` to get back in.

Comment: The question was only about how to inject `NgZone` into the constructor not how to use it... No?

Comment: Otherwise I agree with you ;-)

Comment: I think that the title is too wide. If you have a look at the content of the question, it's clearer: "I'm trying to use NgZone in a small project, but cannot figure out how to bring it in" and "I cannot figure out how to bring NgZone into my class"...

Answer (score 1):

Found that passing Ngzone into constructor has to be preceded with a static parameters array listing the parameters to be passed.  I had tried this last night but didn't realize why or that case mattered.  In any case, once I did, it is now available in the constructor.

```
export class NgZoneDemo {
  progress: number = 0;
  label: string;

  static parameters = [NgZone];
  constructor(ngZone) {
     // use here
  }
  ...
}
```